# Change selected button & images while scrolling

Tags: html, css

On my html I have 3 buttons(will be seen on my page on one section) and each button has a related image. When you start from the top, you will see the 3 buttons on the left and on the right the image from the button that is selected.It will start at first with the first button selected.

The idea is while scrolling down until some height, I want to change the button that is active to the second one and also change the image on the right. Then when continue scrolling again it should select the third button and its image.

Which event or css styling should I use to have this behavior ? Should I use intersection observer ?

I want to use Html, css & js

```
<section
  style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; padding-left: 100px; height: auto; position: sticky; top: 0"
>
  <button style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red">
    Button 1
  </button>
  <button style="width: 100px; height: 100px">Button 2</button>
  <button style="width: 100px; height: 100px">Button 3</button>
  <button style="width: 100px; height: 100px">Button 4</button>
  <button style="width: 100px; height: 100px">Button 5</button>
  <button style="width: 100px; height: 100px">Button 6</button>
  <button style="width: 100px; height: 100px">Button 7</button>
</section>
<section style="height: 200px">Section 2</section>
<section style="height: 200px">Section 3</section>
<section style="height: 200px">Section 4</section>
<section style="height: 200px">Section 5</section>
```

Comment: Adding an event listener for scroll and checking `window.scrollY` is the way to go. I wouldn't use IntersectionObserver for this.

Comment: And how can I handle the height of the sticky content(that has to be 3 times the size of it) and having scrolling there also ?

Comment: Can you provide the HTML for the button and images? It makes answering your question much easier.

Comment: I want to change the image src and the background color of the second Option(as to be the selected one)

Comment: Could you explain a bit morewhat you mean by 'some height' - is it in fact when the user has scrolled down to certain content in the page or is it indeed a certain height (in px or % and if so how do you do a responsive site?).

Comment: Yep. I have a section that is not shown on the screen until you do some scrolldown. When you get to that section you will see the tree buttons, with the first one selected. The idea is that once you scrolldown and get to the final of the section, it's continue scrolling on the same section but now with the second button selected. The same happens with the third one. @AHaworth

Answer (score 0):

IntersectionObserver could be useful here.

Set up just one observer and then observer.observe(each of your sections).

If something isIntersecting highlight its related button and put its image to be shown. If !isIntersecting, remove its button highlight.

Look at the details of options you can set on MDN.

In particular, you will have to decide how much of a section has to come into view before you set its highlight and image and which section ‘wins’ if several sections are in view at once.

Let me know if you need further help, but please include some sections in your question’s code to make it easier to see what is required.

Comment: I have those sections. What I want is when scrolling 200px down, the second button should have the background color on red. Then after 200px more, the 3rd button.....so on until you pass all the buttons and then you continue with the other sections of your page @A Haworth

Comment: Do the highlights go away at some point? For example, when the next section comes into view, or do they remain while their related section is in view - ie can you have more than one link highlighted at a time? Have you tried my code with your HTML? (at 200px most of the sections will be in view on a desktop BTW).

Comment: Yep, when all the buttons have been changed with backgorund color, then when they continue scrolling into the next sextion, the buttons sections should dissapear. Yeah, about the 200px it was an example because my idea is to have bigger sections

Comment: So, when a setion gets to the top its button is highlighted. Is the button of the previous section unhighlighted at this point?

Comment: Always there is only 1 highlighted button.
From 0-200px => only first button highlighted
From 200-400px => only second button highlighted
From 400-600px => only third button highlighted
.....and so on.

The idea is tho make this transition of changing highlighted while scrolling but always keep the section with all the buttons STICKY until it finish highlighting all the buttons